# What's the variance of this Ito integral?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am reading stochastic calculus and I have understood that the process
$$X=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}}dW_t$$
has normal distribution with mean zero.  How can I find the variance of $X$?

Comment: Your question is not about Quantitative Finance.

Comment: Why?. My question belongs stochastic calculus and I think that it is so simple.

Comment: Why do you think that your question is so simple? Do you know the answer!?

Comment: Check Proposition 1 of http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/390/Lecture6.pdf

Comment: "I am reading stochastic calculus"? Could you please give a source.

Comment: Unfortunately not in English and I have not the it's pdf.

Comment: Realy I don't know it's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E^P}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}}dW_t\right]=0 $$
thus
$$\sigma^2=\mathbb{Var^P}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}}dW_t\right)=\mathbb{E^P}\left[\left(\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}}dW_t\right)^2\right] $$ 
By application of [Ito's isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), we have
$$\sigma^2=\mathbb{E^P}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}}\right)^2dt\right]=\mathbb{E^P}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}dt\right]=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}dt\tag 1$$
we know (See Maclaurin Series of $\tan^{-1}x$ in [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html))
$$\tan^{-1}t=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}t^{2n-1}$$
hence
$$\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}t^{2n-2}$$
and
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}dt=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}t^{2n-2}\right)dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}t^{2n-2}dt$$
therefore
$$I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^2}t^{2n-1}\Big{|}_{0}^{1}\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^2}=\color{red}{G}\tag 2$$
where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

$(1)$ and $(2)$
$$\sigma^2=G\simeq  0.916$$

Comment: Impressive. If you had not seen this before, even more so.

Comment: Nice answer indeed!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html

Comment: @Kiwiakos Yes $\operatorname{Ti}_2(1)=G$